# implementing AVLTree and Node for it

Tags: c#, avl-tree

I need to implement an AVLTree where every Node is an Actor. Any suggestion how to implement this would a great help thanks! I have an AVLTree what is working but with a T item not with a whole class. How should I modify that tree?

```
       class Actor
     {
string name, detail;
LinkedList<Albume> albumes;
//add each property that you want
Actor( String name, String detail, LinkedList<Albume> albumes)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.detail = detail;
    this.albumes = albumes;
}
     }
    class Albume {
string name { get; set; }
string detail { get; set; }

        }
```